# Quais as extensões suportadas por $_FILES?

Tags: php

No meu sistema o usuário pode incluir arquivos dentro de um comentário. O problema é que algumas extensões de arquivos estão dando erro (por exemplo deu erro em uma planilha de Excel).

Queria saber se tem como configurar para ele salvar todos os tipos de arquivos ou se essa é uma limitação mesmo e dai eu criarei um tratamento de erro devido?

O que eu já tentei :

Procurei na [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/index.php) e aqui mesmo no [Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) mas não  encontrei nada a respeito.

> Obs: Não preciso de código somente um esclarecimento a respeito da
>   variavel $_FILES.

Comment: E qual foi o erro?

Comment: PHP não limita nenhum arquivo, ou extensão, ou *mime type*, "naturalmente", afinal um arquivo é somente informação. Você faz a validação para que o usuário escolha o formato desejado. O que deve ter acontecido é um erro no seu código, poderia mostrar o código onde está ocorrendo o erro?

Comment: @Stormwind não tem nenhuma configuração nem que seja no Apache falando quais são os tipos passíveis de upload? Pensei que tivesse

Comment: Existem [algumas diretivas](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) que podem vir a impedir o upload @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss um dos usuários que me informou a respeito, mas não viu qual o erro que apareceu , estou elaborando um teste e ja posto a respeito

Comment: @Stormwind , não apareceu mensagem de erro a variavel $_FILES simplesmente retornou `["error"]=> int(1) ` , conversei com meu supervisor e ele me disse que provavelmente foi o tamanho do arquivo , acredito que seja isso mesmo pois eu testei com diferentes arquivos e funcionou mas eu criei uma planilha excel bem grande e ela retornou o `["error"]=> int(1) `, vou fazer um tratamente de erro para o tamanho dos arquivos , obrigado a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já foi dito no comentário e pode ser visto em uma resposta no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8876050), PHP não limita nenhum arquivo, ou extensão, ou *mime type*, "*naturalmente*", afinal um arquivo é somente informação. Você faz a validação para que o usuário escolha o formato desejado.

O que aconteceu foi um erro relacionado ao tamanho do *upload*, que ultrapassava as diretivas configuradas, [como você mesmo disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257050/quais-as-extens%C3%B5es-suportadas-por-files/257103#comment527215_257050). Pode confirmar o que cada código retornado significa [neste link da documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Quando se possui a superglobal `$_FILES['error']` com valor 1, está escrito:

> Value: 1; The uploaded file **exceeds** the `upload_max_filesize` directive in php.ini.

Que em tradução livre seria:

> Valor: 1; O arquivo carregado **excede** a diretiva `upload_max_filesize` no php.ini.

Para fazer a mudança, acesse o `php.ini` e faça mudanças conforme necessário, nessa linha, que controla o tamanho máximo permitido para *uploads*:

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
```

Após a modificação do arquivo `php.ini`, você precisa reiniciar seu servidor HTTP para usar a nova configuração.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, ja estou arrumando aqui